# ubuntu cannot boot after modifying /etc/passwd

Tags: boot, passwd

The following are the steps I *destroyed* my ubuntu:

1. I installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 in my computer;
2. I modified the **/etc/default/grub** and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT = 0`, then I cannot see the Grub screen; *(This is what I wanted.)*
3. I modified the **/etc/passwd** and set `username:x:1000:1000::` to be `username:x:0:0::`, then the system asked me to create a new user when I reboot the system. *(I intended to raise the privilege of the username.)*
4. The result is that I cannot boot the system anymore.
5. If I press ESC when booting, it will show `A start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up (~min ~s/no limit)`.
6. The installation CD can still work.

I need to recover the system.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the root filesystem using the installation CD and reverting `/etc/passwd`?

Comment: @Torin Thanks for your comment. I tried mounting it but I can only see the files under the directory of username. That is I cannot find the file `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Sounds like you have seperate partitions for home and root. There should be another mountable partition containing your root which will contain `/etc/passwd`

Comment: And it's weird that when I run `sudo chroot /mnt`, it will hint `failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`. But I indeed see the file `/bin/bash`.

Comment: You're mounting the wrong filesystem then.

Comment: @Torin @Kusalananda I really appreciate your comments. I indeed mounted the wrong filesystem. Running the two commands `sudo mount *** /mnt` and `sudo chroot /mnt`, and then reverting `/etc/passwd` can solve the problem.